# Excel word, timer continues even if i turn off

Tags: timer, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins, word-addins

I created a timer

```
void Application_DocumentOpen(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document Doc)
{
                System.Timers.Timer timer=new System.Timers.Timer(30000);
                timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => ExcelFileSendToAPI(Doc.FullName);
                timer.Start();
}
```

ExcelFileSendToAPI method makes an api request every 30 seconds after the file is opened.
**There is nothing wrong** but Even if I open 2 excel applications and close an excel application, it continues to make requests in the background.
How can I turn off the timer after the application is closed?

This problem exists in word, excel and powerpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your code in the timer_tick function rather than in the Document_Open function. I provided a code sample for you in your other question that effectively uses the timer_tick event.

```
Timer Timer1 = new Timer();

void Application_DocumentOpen(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document Doc)
 {
            InitializeTimer();
}

void InitializeTimer()
{
     Timer1.Interval = 30000;
     Timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer1_Tick);
}

private void Timer1_Tick (Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DocumentEditingSendToServer(Doc.Application.ActiveDocument);
}
```

And in your document_close event, you need to stop your timer.